# Potential rendering artifacts in generated mesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am generating a procedural mesh, however my calculated normals seems to be causing some weird artifacts when lighting / rendering.

[image: normal issues]

I have a grid of points / vertices on which i calculate each vertex-normal based on the four directly adjacent verticies.

```
        // Points for normal calculation:
        //          c
        //         /|
        //        / |
        //       a--p--b
        //          | /
        //          |/
        //          d     
        
        var normalA = math.cross(posC - posP, posA - posP);
        var normalB = math.cross(posD - posP, posB - posP);

        var normal = math.normalize(normalA + normalB);
```

There might be something wrong with how i calculate these normals, but I've tried a few different approaches as to how they get averaged and what influences them.

Calling unity RecalculateNormals() essentially gives the same results.
Is this just what these normals can give me in term of detail or am i missing something fundamental?

The only assumption I currently have is that the triangles are oriented wrong, and they need to be better aligned in order to represent the meshes curvature. Is there no way around this?

Comment: I think the polygons at the base of the mountains makes an accordion. They make a zig-zag perpendicular to the diagonal line. I think that this is not a problem with the normal calculation. The mesh would have to be subdivided further at places with a big curvature.